# Anidar where between y LIKE en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where, like

Buenas tengo una consulta en la cuando necesito filtrar por un rango de fecha y buscar en un campo con un LIKE varias condiciones la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    cargos
WHERE
    fecha BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-28'
        AND codigo LIKE 'la%'
        OR codigo LIKE '%1199300%'
        OR codigo LIKE '%gra0700%'
```

El filtro de de búsqueda de los 3 códigos funciona pero el de la fecha no, en que estaré fallando quedo atento gracias

Comment: Entiendo que tienes un problema de lógica, te faltan unos paréntesis: `AND ( codigo ...  OR codigo LIKE '%gra0700%')`

Comment: Probaste usando solo el campo fecha sin los LIKE para ver si retorna algo?, probé tu consulta y funciona sin problemas.

Comment: En realidad estoy asumiendo que para cualquiera de los códigos, quieres que las filas cumplan el rango de fechas, pero en realidad deberías explicar un poco mejor que es lo que buscas filtrar

Comment: @PatricioMoracho gracias me funciono de esa manera

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el tipo de dato del campo fecha.
el problema puede estar asociado a la interpretación.

por ejemplo.
si el tipo de dato `fecha` es `date` (formato YYYY-MM-DD), en tu consulta lo puedes colocar asi.

```
fecha BETWEEN '2021-07-01' AND '2021-07-28'
```

si el tipo de dato `fecha` es `datetime` (formato YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), en tu consulta lo puedes colocar asi,

```
fecha BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-28 00:00:00'
```

si el tipo de datos `fecha` es `timestamp` (equivalente al tipo anterior, DATETIME, YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS), en tu consulta puedes colocar asi,

```
fecha BETWEEN '2021-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2021-07-28 00:00:00'
```